Trying to run a one-line Racket program and it doesn't like #lang?
This code:
#lang racket

(display (vector->string #(#\H #\i #\!)))

is giving me this error message
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.14 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student; memory limit: 128 MB.
read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled
  possible reason: not allowed again inside a module that already starts `#lang`, or not enabled for interactive evaluation

when I try to run it. (also "#lang" gets highlighted with red/pink background in the editor) I have this exact statement at the start of two other programs that do run so I don't know why there is an error for this one. If I take "#lang racket" out it tells me it doesn't know what "display" is so "not allowed again" doesn't appear to be true.

If #lang has already been used to specify a language that doesn't include display, it could be true.

How are you trying to run it?

Also, don't use Beginning Student Language unless you're actually working through the parts of HtDP that say to use it.

@Shawn MenuBar->Racket->Run  (but just tried on the command line and it gives the same error)

racket yourfile.rkt gives that error?

In DrRacket, go to Language->Choose Language and select Racket instead of BSL

@Shawn Changing to Language->ChooseLanguage->"The Racket Language" does fix the error. But the weird thing is that setting in the IDE impacts the command line racket. If I set the IDE to "Teaching Languages->Advanced Student" and save, I get the error on the command line (as well as in the IDE).

This error was caused by the setting of MenuBar->Language->ChooseLanguage. It was set to "Teaching Languages"->Beginning Student (The error also occurs if "Advanced Student" is selected). Setting it to "The Racket Language" causes the error to go away. The Teaching Languages setting probably sets it to a (subset of) regular Scheme .
The error also occurs on the command line (racket myprogram.rkt), depending on the Language setting that is in the IDE (the "Save" floppy disk icon has to be pressed in order to change the command line behavior from a new Language setting).
